# Why my stopwatch isn't working in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, stopwatch

I am trying to create a stopwatch for my app in Android Studio using [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-chronometer-timer-widget-for-your-apps/) tutorial, and while the app itself is running smoothly, when I press the 'Start' button nothing happens.

Below is my code:

activity_third.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/stopwatch"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/start"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/stop"/>

</LinearLayout>

<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chronometer"
    android:format="%s"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40sp"/>
```

ThirdActivity.java:

```
public class ThirdActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Chronometer chronometer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

        chronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
        findViewById(R.id.start).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.stop).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.start:
                chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                chronometer.start();
                break;
            case R.id.stop:
                chronometer.stop();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the buttons aren't working and how to fix them? Thank you!

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: No--the app is running normally on the emulator; it is just the buttons that don't seem to work.

Comment: I try to run with your code, it running normally. Can you put LogCat `Log.d("DEBUG", "start")` in your switch case for check button onClickListener is work?

Comment: I did what you asked, but the 'Start' button still didn't work... Thank you for trying, though! :)

Comment: Check the IDs being passed into the onClick switch statement matches the start id

Comment: @Chris: I'm pretty sure they match--why? Do you see any anomalies?

Comment: see my answer, that code worked correctly

Answer (score 0):

I used the code you posted above and it works, The only issue was the full layout wasn't copy and pasted.

Check the activity implements View.onClickListener and not another one.

Here is the Layout I used

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Stopwatch"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stop"/>

</LinearLayout>
    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/chronometer"
        android:format="%s"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40sp"/>

</LinearLayout>


public class TestActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
private Chronometer chronometer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    chronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
    findViewById(R.id.start).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.stop).setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.start:
            chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            chronometer.start();
            break;
        case R.id.stop:
            chronometer.stop();
            break;
    }
}
```

}

This code worked an it started the timer displaying to screen.

Comment: I tried your code in a new project, and it worked, but for some reason it doesn't work in my own project... ThirdActivity is a child activity of MainActivity; do you think this could affect anything?

Comment: Shouldn't really affect it, it looks like the buttons weren't getting bound. Does the activity definitely implement View.OnClickListener ?

Comment: How do I know if View.OnClickListener has definitely been implemented? The code is exactly as you said, if that's what you mean... On my logcat, it says, "Skipped 136 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." Do you think this could be the source of my error, and if so, do you know how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: I think you are implementing the correct listener then. It hard to tell why its not happening there could be many reasons. Have you debugged your code using a breakpoint to see if the start stopwatch code is ever executed ?